# Why did this CSS behave differently after applying it to my DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm styling a series of books for my library project and I found some .css code that works for what I have in mind.

The html is relatively simple, just two  elements and then all the styling is on that:

```js
function render() {
    const bookContainer = document.createElement("div");
    bookContainer.classList.add("bookContainer");
  
    const newVolume = document.createElement("div");
    newVolume.classList.add("volume");
    bookContainer.appendChild(newVolume);
  
    const img = document.createElement("img");
    newVolume.appendChild(img);
   
    newVolume.innerHTML = "TEST";

    libraryContainer.appendChild(bookContainer);
    };

render()
```

```css
.book-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  perspective: 600px;
}

@keyframes initAnimation {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(-30deg);
  }
}

.volume {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateY(-30deg);
  transition: 1s ease;
  animation: 1s ease 0s 1 initAnimation;
  font-family: "Bookman Old Style", sans-serif;
  color: #ef8a42;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px;
}

.volume:hover {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

.volume > :first-child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  transform: translateZ(25px);
  background-color:yellow;
  border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px #666;
}

.volume::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: ' ';
  left: 0;
  top: 3px;
  width: 48px;
  height: 294px;
  transform: translateX(172px) rotateY(90deg);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, 
    #fff 0%,
    #f9f9f9 5%,
    #fff 10%,
    #f9f9f9 15%,
    #fff 20%,
    #f9f9f9 25%,
    #fff 30%,
    #f9f9f9 35%,
    #fff 40%,
    #f9f9f9 45%,
    #fff 50%,
    #f9f9f9 55%,
    #fff 60%,
    #f9f9f9 65%,
    #fff 70%,
    #f9f9f9 75%,
    #fff 80%,
    #f9f9f9 85%,
    #fff 90%,
    #f9f9f9 95%,
    #fff 100%
    );
}

.volume::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: ' ';
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  transform: translateZ(-25px);
  background-color: #01060f;
  border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
  box-shadow: -10px 0 50px 10px #666;
}
```

```html
<div id="libraryContainer">

  <div class="book-container" >
    <div class="volume">
      <img/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But the result is two different shapes! Do you know why this is? Is something in the DOM affecting the execution of the CSS?

EDIT: Clarifying the problem:

When the provided CSS is applied to the html block, it creates a yellow book with a black cover, shown in perspective, with the yellow cover appearing as a parallelogram.

When the provided CSS is applied to the js DOM, the book that's created has no perspective and just appears as a rectangle.

Comment: Please clarify what the problem is. It looks like a book with a yellow cover and a blue back cover. All of which looks fine.

Comment: You're wiping the earlier appended image away when you set `innerHTML` of `newVolume` .

Comment: Still having problem understanding what u want? can u clarify a bit more? after applying js you get a rectangle, what do u mean by that? I am running the code snippet and seeing a yellow book(3D) while putting cursor on it, it moves. What's the problem you're having there?

Comment: `"message": "ReferenceError: libraryContainer is not defined",`

Comment: thanks for looking! I updated the code for the js DOM. That js DOM code with the CSS styling gets me a black rectangle with no perspective, unlike the html with the same CSS styling, which gets me a yellow rectangle with perspective.

Comment: thanks @connexo -- yeah, libraryContainer is just another div in the html, let me update that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All changes on Javascript.
First: The class was wrong `book-container` and not `bookContainer`.
Second: If you want write something, or insert content (image and text) on the cover you need a `div` and put here what you need.

```js
function render() {
  const bookContainer = document.createElement("div");
  bookContainer.classList.add("book-container");

  const newVolume = document.createElement("div");
  newVolume.classList.add("volume");
  bookContainer.appendChild(newVolume);

  const div = document.createElement("div");
  newVolume.appendChild(div);
  
  div.innerHTML = "TEST";
  
  // With image:
  div.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6e/Vulpes_vulpes_Mallnitz_01.jpg/1920px-Vulpes_vulpes_Mallnitz_01.jpg')";

div.style.backgroundSize = "cover";

  
  
  


  libraryContainer.appendChild(bookContainer);
};

render()
```

```css
.book-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  perspective: 600px;
}

@keyframes initAnimation {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(-30deg);
  }
}

.volume {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateY(-30deg);
  transition: 1s ease;
  animation: 1s ease 0s 1 initAnimation;
  font-family: "Bookman Old Style", sans-serif;
  color: #ef8a42;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px;
}

.volume:hover {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

.volume> :first-child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  transform: translateZ(25px);
  background-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px #666;
}

.volume::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: ' ';
  left: 0;
  top: 3px;
  width: 48px;
  height: 294px;
  transform: translateX(172px) rotateY(90deg);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #fff 0%, #f9f9f9 5%, #fff 10%, #f9f9f9 15%, #fff 20%, #f9f9f9 25%, #fff 30%, #f9f9f9 35%, #fff 40%, #f9f9f9 45%, #fff 50%, #f9f9f9 55%, #fff 60%, #f9f9f9 65%, #fff 70%, #f9f9f9 75%, #fff 80%, #f9f9f9 85%, #fff 90%, #f9f9f9 95%, #fff 100%);
}

.volume::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: ' ';
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  transform: translateZ(-25px);
  background-color: #01060f;
  border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
  box-shadow: -10px 0 50px 10px #666;
}
```

```html
<div id="libraryContainer">

  <div class="book-container">
    <div class="volume">
      <img/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you. Feel kind of dumb about the spelling error, but the clarification on the <div> needed helps a lot.  

Comment: @acchang I added the image too :)

Comment: To be honest I didn't explain well, I just gave you a solution. But the problem is that you first insert the image in `newVolume.appendChild(img)` and then you replace all content with `newVolume.innerHTML = "TEST";`  deleting the image and the cover gone.

Comment: The solution was plenty helpful, since reduced the code to what I needed for stackoverflow, but then I had to rework it to put into this bigger project I'm working on, and then I got an idea of what you did. But the explanation helps a lot too, to confirm what I thought was going on.